# How to use multiple background colors for different string value in a particular row of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

I have CSV file with multiple columns and I am searching some string in column 5 and highlighting the row for diffrent string.
As of now I am able to use just two colours but I want to use more colors for more string into it.
Example for

```
     x['4']="abc" --->I want to use yellow color 
     x['4']="xyz" --->I want to use grey  color
     x['4']="pqr" --->I want to use green color
```

For two color I am using

```
         n = len(df.columns) 
         df.style.apply(lambda x: ["background-color: red"]*n if x['4']== 'ERROR' else ["background-color: white"]*n, axis = 1)
```

What changes should we make for multiple colours

Answer (score 0):

Create dictionary for background colors by values and pass to [`Styler.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html) for mapping by `dict.get`, if no match is returned empty value:

```
d = {'abc':'background-color:yellow',
     'xyz':'background-color:grey',
     'pqr':'background-color:green'}

df.style.applymap(lambda x: d.get(x,''), subset=['4'])
```

Another idea with [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and `axis=1`, for mapping use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: x.map(d).fillna(''), subset=['4'], axis=1)
```

**Sample data**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'4':['abc','xyz','pqr','temp'],
                   '5':range(4)})
```

Test in jupyter notebook:

[image]

EDIT:

For coloring rows use custom function:

```
def hightlight(x):
    d = {'abc':'background-color:yellow',
         'xyz':'background-color:grey',
         'pqr':'background-color:green'}

    #DataFrame with same index and columns names as original filled repeated strings
    out = np.repeat(x['4'].map(d).fillna('').to_numpy(), len(x.columns)).reshape(x.shape)
    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=x.index, columns=x.columns)

df.style.apply(hightlight, axis=None)
```

Comment: If I have to color a complete row with the same color as of the column than what changes should I make?

Comment: @SIDDHARTHCHAUHAN - answer was edited.